# Data structure and algorithms for a directed cyclic graph (F#)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, f#, directed-graph

I'm trying to analyse an application where the assembly references *should* be a directed-acyclic-graph, but aren't. There is also a related problem of sub-assemblies referencing different versions of one sub-sub-assembly ([think Escher...](http://www.mcescher.com/Gallery/back-bmp/LW389.jpg))

What I want to do is analyse each assembly-subassembly pair and build up a picture of where things are wrong.

I need some guidance on what would be a good data structure for this. I'm not too sure that I can build up an immutable one, but I don't mind having it mutable internally then transformed to immutable at the end.

The other part of the question is what kind of algorithms I should use for filling the data structure, and also afterwards for 'analysing' the problems.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/), it analyzes your assemblies and detects dependency cycles.

If you really want to do this yourself, I'd use [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) to model the dependency graphs, it also includes graph algorithms, like topological sort.

Comment: Thanks, the situation is actually slightly more complicated that my question implies. We have a home-made system which 'tracks' the dependencies, but it is patently not up-to-date. My aim is to find all the places it is not working. So your second suggestion looks to be more useful for me.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't mind having it mutable internally then transformed to immutable at the end.

You may well find it easier to use immutable data structures throughout. In particular, you can easily represent a graph as a `Map` from source nodes to sets of destination nodes. For a topological sort, you want efficient access to the source nodes of a destination node so you may want to augment your graph with another `Map` going in the opposite direction.

I just implemented this in F# and the topological sort is just 12 lines of code... :-)

Comment: Jon, I'm in need of a topological sort function. Any chance you can share?

Comment: I wrote an article about it here: http://fsharpnews.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/graph-algorithms-topological-sort-and.html

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is called "Topological sorting". Wikipedia has a good overview:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sort